# How can i Formatting a date field in a ModelForm to dd/mm/yy in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my project settings.py i try this :

```
USE_L10N = False

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

In my models.py i try this :

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    Married_Status = (
        ("1", "Married"),
        ("2", "Unmarried"),
    )

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Age = models.IntegerField()
    Married_Status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Married_Status, default="Unmarried")
    
    Birth_Date = models.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

It's show a error "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'"
I read django document and other stackoverflow question answer but i could not understand.

I want input from user like : 17/03/1998

I'm a noob to python and Django so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Setting.py :

```
USE_L10N = False
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

In model.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    Married_Status = (
        ("1", "Married"),
        ("2", "Unmarried"),
    )

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Age = models.IntegerField()
    Married_Status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Married_Status, default="Unmarried")
    
    Birth_Date = models.DateField(default="Day/Month/Year")
```

That show like : Day/Month/Year